# SVG symbols are not available on other computers

Tags: qgis, svg

I created some layers with SVG symbols. Those symbols are saved on the server, as it is not possible to store it in the database (postgis). Every computer can access to the server. But if I open the project on other computers - instead of the SVG symbols there are question tags.

Comment: Not used QGIS on a server before so this is a wild guess but perhaps add the path to the SVG folder in _Settings > Options > System > SVG paths_?

Comment: If you open the styles dialog of layer properties and select the SVG marker in the Symbol groupbox, you can at the bottom right see the path to the SVG. I guess this is a local and not a server path.

Comment: @ Joseph: This might help, I'll try this as soon as I can use my boss' computer and give feedback then.

Comment: @Jakob: Good guess..I thought this too on first sight. Do I have somehow to define the server path (e.g. afp://)? The SVGs are on a server and my path looks like Volume/servername/subfolder/subfolder. thx!

Comment: If you have the server path mapped to a volume, just add it like Joseph says. The styles in folder will be added as a new SVG  Group. You can also use the \\ip\folders like a path if the server is not mapped. (QGIS 2.10.1)